# CSS3 slider transition effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have question about css slider transition.

I want to make transition like Fade in L with transition code:

```
{
    $Duration: 1200,
    x: 0.3,
    $During: {
        $Left: [0.3, 0.7]
    },
    $Easing: {
        $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic,
        $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear
    },
    $Opacity: 2
}
```

from this page: http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html

But Im using responsiveslides: http://responsiveslides.com

is there any way to implement this effect to responsiveslides?

I found this piece of code in responsiveslides js:

```
  if (supportsTransitions) {
    $slide
      .show()
      .css({
        // -ms prefix isn't needed as IE10 uses prefix free version
        "-webkit-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-out",
        "-moz-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-out",
        "-o-transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-out",
        "transition": "opacity " + fadeTime + "ms ease-out"
      });
  }
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code, maybe this can help you!

Code working here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EnmGI (check the checkbox)

HTML

```
<h1>Incredibly Basic Slider</h1>
<div id="slider">
  <ul id="imgs">
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>

<div class="slider_option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);  

html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #58DDAF;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

JQUERY

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
       moveLeft();
    }, 3000);
  });

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };
});
```